# How to decrypt AES128 encryption with provided string, mode, key, padding and key

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, aes

I am trying to decrypt an AES encryption with the following information provided:

> - Encryption type: AES 128
> - Mode: CBC
> - Padding: PKCS5 (.net uses PKCS7)
> - Password(key): jayjay
> - Encryption ref: https://zenu.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/aes-128bit-cross-platform-java-and-c-encryption-compatibility/

Example provided:

> - Encrypted string: vsiv+Tv0H9Tz0GHtf2S4KBXVV+0L6Wr0xCWwA1QOPs8rnyRxNDDgH4ogo5Mm+wrzEW6uFD2kdFI2IcSTx+RMu
>     3817A7n1/ZLCjqq6ZTXI3QZbWgr6AH3SOGM/lcnud4EROGUiZuTiWIBjxTy+q/8tA==
> - Decrypted string (expected):   BadgeID^CustIDLookup^First Name^Last Name^Title^Company^Address 1^Address
>     2^City^State^Zip^Country^Phone^Email

Unfortunately without actually knowing how it has been encrypted, it seems that the decoding is not fully working.

I've created a category of NSString with the following method:

```
- (NSString *)decryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {

    NSData *stringData = [self dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    size_t decryptedDataLength = [stringData length] + kCCKeySizeAES128;
    NSMutableData *decryptedData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:kCCKeySizeAES128 + decryptedDataLength];

    size_t numberOfBytes;

    CCCryptorStatus status = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                                     kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                     kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                     [keyData bytes],
                                     kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                     nil,
                                     [stringData bytes], [stringData length],
                                     decryptedData.mutableBytes, [decryptedData length],
                                     &numberOfBytes);

    if (status == kCCSuccess) {
        return [decryptedData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Status: %d", status);
        return @"";
    }
}
```

I get a kCCSuccess status but the string is not as expected. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _I get a successful decoding but the string is not as expected_ - between you and me, one of us has an incorrect definition of the word _successful_ ;)

Comment: I meant that the status is kCCSuccess - thanks for pointing that out @mah

Comment: The encrypted string is in base64 encoded. Do you decode that first and then use the decoded data to decrypt? Usually the source string is encrypted and then encoded to base64. So the decrypt process should be reverse. Decode the base64 to create the encrypted data and then decrypt that data to get the source string.

Comment: Don't confuse keys with passwords. A key must have a specific length, for example 16 bytes for AES-128. If you want to generate a key from a password, then you need to know how this generation works. I don't see any reference to common key derivation functions such as PBKDF2.

Comment: Just use [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor). It is portable and has support for authenticated encryption.

Comment: Btw, how come you dont know how its encrypted. Without knowing how its encrypted its complicated to decrypt it. You have to use trial and error method.

Comment: Thanks for your input @PradeepK. It is a challenge : )

Comment: Thank you for your input, @ArtjomB. I am pretty new to encryption/decryption and security with iOS. I will checkout RNCryptor and have a look at difference between key/password.